# Laravel - 8.* Images libraries

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I want to resize images that I upload on my page, but to do that I need library that will handle it.

I tried to use Intervention Images, everything was fine untill it came to run it. It requires GD Library, which first of all is supposted to by on my XAMPP, php.ini but really isnt. (After all there would be a problem with installing it on server where i would put my page so imo not worth deal.

`GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation.`

Then I tried Nette but it doesnt allow to read file and then resize (or I really missed something) you can just resize you make from this app.

So my question is simple, is there any other Image library that would allow me to **resize** my uploaded images?(that works with laravel 8.*

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is other alternative for image processing library that doesn't use `php-gd` since it's the most powerful image processing extension and natively supported by PHP (reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php).

If the error is on your php extension, you should recheck the `php.ini` configuration and the extension binary file (usually located at php `ext/` directory).

But I highly recommend to use other local development environment such as [Laragon](https://laragon.org/) for easy php extension management.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Intervention Image.
I personally use Imagick (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-imagemagick-and-imagick-php-extension-in-ubuntu) but it seems like you can also use GD for this.
This is where you can install it to your laravel project: http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation
You can now use this library in your code

```
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;
```

Saying the uploaded file is $file you can then resize the image and encode it as a 1024x1024 jpg (png works too).

```
$resize = Image::make($file->getRealPath())->fit(1024)->encode('jpg');
```

Finally you just have to save the image to the storage or work with it as you like

```
$resize->save(storage_path('image.jpg'));
```

Comment: the op already tried `Intervention Image` library. please re read the question .

Comment: But op asked for a gd alternative which I proposed with Imagick

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a package called image intervention. I just used the package for my own project.

Comment: I know you wanted to help me out buddy, but I believe that you didnt read question.